# Trying to access SSRS Web service in my .NET Project using web reference - getting error permissions are insufficient for user

Tags: soap, reporting-services

I am trying to access a SOAP web service in my VB.NET Project so that I can print a report directly to printer without any pop up or confirmation click by user .I tried to access the SOAP web service in my project using this link

http://myservername/reportserver/ReportExecution2010.asmx

But i get the error permissions granted for this user are insufficient to perform this operation .

For a normal report i know that i should go to reports folder and give access to datasets,datasources and any other folder with the id's that i want to deploy and also access.
But i dont know where to give access for accessing SOAP web service .I searched on the internet majority of the solutions are about report access and not web service .

Answer (score 1):

ReportExecution2010.asmx web service uses the same security behaviors as the SSRS website. Try giving your domain\user account the `Content Manager` role within the SSRS website first.